# How to pass object inside the map function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a temp array like below:

```
10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "john", address: "a1", v1: 11.972646011733632, …}
1: {name: "Dave", address: "a2", v1: 11.972646011733632, …}
2: {name: "Sid", address: "a3", v1: 11.972646011733632, …}
```

I have one object to check if the field is required to format or not

```
obj = {
    name: [],
    address: [],
    v1: ['round', 'percentage'],
    v2: ['round', 'percentage'],
    year: []
};
```

What I need is on temp loop check if key in obj and is there is round and percentage then first round to 2 decimal and add '%'.

I want my output like:

```
0: {name: "john", address: "a1", v1: 11.97%, …}
1: {name: "Dave", address: "a2", v1: 16.47%, …}
2: {name: "Sid", address: "a3", v1: 11.37%, …}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine `map` and `reduce` method to return new array of objects and then use `switch` to change values by each array fields in obj.

```js
const data = [{name: "john", address: "a1", v1: 11.972646011733632},
{name: "Dave", address: "a2", v1: 11.972646011733632},
{name: "Sid", address: "a3", v1: 11.972646011733632}]

const obj = {
  name: [],
  address: [],
  v1: ['round', 'percentage'],
  v2: ['round', 'percentage'],
  year: []
};

const result = data.map(o => {
  return Object.entries(o).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    if (obj[k] && obj[k].length) {
      obj[k].forEach(field => {
        switch (field) {
          case 'round':
            v = Math.round(v * 100) / 100
            break;
          case 'percentage':
            v += '%'
            break;
        }
      })
    }
    r[k] = v;
    return r
  }, {})
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generalize formatting of certain keys in an object in the following way.

```js
//takes array of functions like [fn1,fn2]
//  and returns a function: fn(arg)=>fn2(fn1(arg))
const compose = (functions = [(x) => x]) => (arg) =>
  functions.reduce((result, fn) => fn(result), arg);
const round = (decimals) => (x) =>
  parseFloat(x.toFixed(decimals));
const percentage = (x) => x + '%';
const upperCaseName = (x) =>
  x.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1);
//formatters, key 'v1' will be rounded and made a percentage
const formatters = {
  v1: [round(2), percentage],
  name: [upperCaseName],
};

console.log(
  //data
  [
    { name: 'john', address: 'a1', v1: 11.972646011733632 },
  ].map((
    o, //format each key that exist in formatters
  ) =>
    Object.entries(o).reduce(
      (result, [key, value]) => (
        //if compose is passed undefined it'll return x=>x function
        //  so value will not be formatted
        (result[key] = compose(formatters[key])(value)),
        result
      ),
      {},
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code..

```
var obj = {0: {name: "john", address: "a1", v1: 11.972646011733632, v2: 32.35345132541},1: {name: "Dave", address: "a2", v1: 15.972646011733632, v2: 12.35345132541},2: {name: "Sid", address: "a3", v1: 22.972646011733632, v2: 42.35345132541}};
    var length = Object.keys(obj).length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        obj[i].v1 = parseFloat(Math.round(obj[i].v1 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) + ' %';
        obj[i].v2 = parseFloat(Math.round(obj[i].v2 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) + ' %';
    }   
    console.log(obj);
```

Enjoy !!